Is there any other work from ancient India which considers any caste other than Brahmins as superior?
There are 18 Mahasmritis and Upasmritis . Almost all of them are advocating birth based Varna considering Brahmins as superior. I would like to know any similar work which says any caste other than Brahmins as superior.

Ambattha sutta of Buddhism says Kshatriyas are superior to Brahmins;

Then the Buddha addressed Ambaṭṭha, “What do you think, Ambaṭṭha?
Suppose an aristocrat boy was to sleep with a brahmin girl, and they
had a son. Would he receive a seat and water from the brahmins?”
“He would, Mister Gotama.”
“And would the brahmins feed him at an offering of food for ancestors,
an offering of a dish of milk-rice, a sacrifice, or a feast for
guests?”
“They would.”
“And would the brahmins teach him the hymns or not?”
“They would.”
“And would he be kept from the women or not?”.
“He would not.”
“And would the aristocrats anoint him as king?”
“No, Mister Gotama. Why is that? Because his maternity is unsuitable.”
“What do you think, Ambaṭṭha? Suppose a brahmin boy was to sleep with
an aristocrat girl, and they had a son. Would he receive a seat and
water from the brahmins?”
“He would, Mister Gotama.”
“And would the brahmins feed him at an offering of food for ancestors,
an offering of a dish of milk-rice, a sacrifice, or a feast for
guests?”
“They would.”
“And would the brahmins teach him the hymns or not?”
“They would.”
“And would he be kept from the women or not?”
“He would not.”
“And would the aristocrats anoint him as king?”
“No, Mister Gotama. Why is that? Because his paternity is unsuitable.”
“And so, Ambaṭṭha, the aristocrats are superior and the brahmins
inferior, whether comparing women with women or men with men. What do
you think, Ambaṭṭha? Suppose the brahmins for some reason were to
shave a brahmin’s head, inflict him with a sack of ashes, and banish
him from the nation or the city. Would he receive a seat and water
from the brahmins?”
“No, Mister Gotama.”
“And would the brahmins feed him at an offering of food for ancestors,
an offering of a dish of milk-rice, a sacrifice, or a feast for
guests?”
“No, Mister Gotama.”
“And would the brahmins teach him the hymns or not?”
“No, Mister Gotama.”
“And would he be kept from the women or not?”
“He would be.”
“What do you think, Ambaṭṭha? Suppose the aristocrats for some reason
were to shave an aristocrat’s head, inflict him with a sack of ashes,
and banish him from the nation or the city. Would he receive a seat
and water from the brahmins?”
“He would, Mister Gotama.”
“And would the brahmins feed him at an offering of food for ancestors,
an offering of a dish of milk-rice, a sacrifice, or a feast for
guests?”
“They would.”
“And would the brahmins teach him the hymns or not?”
“They would.”
“And would he be kept from the women or not?”
“He would not.”
“At this point, Ambaṭṭha, that aristocrat has reached rock bottom,
with head shaven, inflicted with a sack of ashes, and banished from
city or nation. Yet still the aristocrats are superior and the
brahmins inferior.
'Moreover it was one of the Brahmâ gods, Sanam-kumâra, who uttered
this stanza
"The Kshatriya is the best of those among this folk
who put their trust in lineage.    But he who is perfect in wisdom and righteousness, he is the best among gods and men."

The last highlighted part basically means among kshatriyas those who put trust in their lineage are superior and  kshatriyas who are perfect in wisdom and righteousness are superior among god and men.

Not really a Hindu religious text, right? So might not be right to post on a Hinduism site.
